# Why attempt to find 'b' in golden ratio ends up with odd results?

Tags: number-theory

Imagine that you have a line segment which is divided into larger and smaller segment. You want to find a golden ratio for the longer segment $a$, and shorter one $b$. As you know the phi number which equals to $1.618$ and let's say you know the $b$ parameter, you try to write $1.618 = a/b = (a + b) / a$. However, no matter what you'll do - you can never get the proper result for $b$ if for example $a = 3,82$ and you perform : $1.618 = 3.82 / b$, then divide both sides by $1/3.82$ and then divide $1.618$ by $3.82$ in order to get $b$ result. Why is this happening?

Comment: Note that in your final equation you are calculating $\dfrac 1b$ instead of $b$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I twisted things over, I have such a nasty habit when it comes to math and explaining my thoughts ;). Thanks for the answer. To elaborate better my problem : I'm aiming to make a let's say 'a logo'. I wanted to learn the principles of golden ratio in order to make more eye appealing designs. One of the things which golden ratio would help with are proportions. However, how can I know the values of 'a' and 'b' if all I know is just the fact that phi is 1.618 ?

Comment: $\varphi=a/b\iff a=\varphi b\iff b=\varphi^{-1}a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking from an aesthetic point of view for your 'logo example' as opposed to a more mathematical interpretation we can build a couple easy to use functions starting with,

$$\frac{width}{height}=\frac{\phi}{1}$$(with $\phi$ being equal to 1.618...)

If you have a known height for the logo and want to know what the width should be you can use,
$${width}={\phi}*{height}$$
And if you know the width but need the height,
$${height}=\frac{width}{\phi}$$
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> However, how can I know the values of 'a' and 'b' if all I know is just the fact that phi is 1.618 ?

You can't; you only know that the *ratio* of $a$ to $b$ is 1.618...; basically, this is a reflection of the fact that there are many rectangles with these proportions, but choosing the scale is left entirely up to you; that is you can choose any $a$ you want.

In the example you give, setting $a = 3.82$ makes

$$
1.618... = 3.82/b\\ \Rightarrow b = 3.82/1.618... = 2.361...
$$

You can check this is consistent with the other equation:

$$
(a + b)/a = (6.18...)/3.82 = 1.618...
$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll check it in a spare time. I would like to ask you why you wrote that b = 3.82/1.618 instead of b = 1.618/3.82 ? (Multiplying both sides by 1/3.82 in order to get rid of numbers near b parameter).

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1/3.82$ yields $1.618/3.82 = 1/b$, which is equivalent to $3.82/1.618 = b$.

Comment: My goodness, only now I've noticed my mistake. What a shame ! Thank you all for shaking me up !!!

Comment: No shame in making mistakes as long as you learn from them. You're welcome!

Comment: I was wondering over one more thing :). I would like to know how can I calculate proper spacing between let's say an icon and a text box of the entire shape which is a logo. Also... how can I properly adjust the height of the icon and text box so they stay in a perfect Golden Ratio ? Thank you

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I understand your question. It might be best if you start a new question (you should include a link back to this one), and then elaborate on this.